# VSTO Bug - GetVstoObject returning wrong worksheet

Tags: vb.net, excel, vsto, add-in

I'm developing an application-level add-in for Excel using VSTO on VS2013. My code works for all my worksheets, except for one. I found out that the function GetVstoObject is returning a sheet different than the sheet given as parameter.

This is my Immediate Window RIGHT NOW:

```
?sheet.Name
"Sheet2"
?Globals.Factory.GetVstoObject(sheet).Name
"Sheet1"
```

Why is this happening? I read that this return is only calculated once and for the subsequent calls, the cached value is returned. There is some way to clear this cache?

EDIT:

On this workbook, I have two worksheets, the first named as "Sheet1" and the second named "Sheet2". I never renamed or copied one of these sheets, I just started a new workbook and created an additional worksheet.

This is my code for debugging:

```
Dim sheet1 As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet = formMapeamento.wb.Worksheets.Item(1)
Dim sheet2 As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet = formMapeamento.wb.Worksheets.Item(2)

Dim sheet1_vsto = Globals.Factory.GetVstoObject(sheet1)
Dim sheet2_vsto = Globals.Factory.GetVstoObject(sheet2)

Dim sheet1_vsto_inner = sheet1_vsto.InnerObject
Dim sheet2_vsto_inner = sheet2_vsto.InnerObject
```

And this is my immediate window right now, with more data.

```
'Checking "Sheet1". Everithing looks as expected
?sheet1.Name
"Sheet1"
?sheet1.Index
1
?sheet1.CodeName
"Sheet1"
?Globals.Factory.HasVstoObject(sheet1)
True
?sheet1_vsto.Name
"Sheet1"
?sheet1_vsto.Index
1
?sheet1_vsto.CodeName
"Sheet1"
?sheet1_vsto_inner.Name
"Sheet1"
?sheet1_vsto_inner.Index
1
?sheet1_vsto_inner.CodeName
"Sheet1"

'Checking "Sheet2". STRANGE VALUES
?sheet2.Name
"Sheet2"
?sheet2.Index
2
?sheet2.CodeName
"Sheet1"
?Globals.Factory.HasVstoObject(sheet2)
False
?sheet2_vsto.Name
"Sheet1"
?sheet2_vsto.Index
1
?sheet2_vsto.CodeName
"Sheet1"
?sheet2_vsto_inner.Name
"Sheet1"
?sheet2_vsto_inner.Index
1
?sheet2_vsto_inner.CodeName
"Sheet1"
```

This problem suddenly started happening. Before that, both sheets were returning correct values. After I run my code some times (the code iterates over some ranges, add and remove windows comboboxes on the worksheets, displays some forms and writes on CustomXMLParts) `sheet2_vsto` started responding as `sheet1_vsto`. I saved this workbook to study the problem,  to avoid this from happening with my users.

I couldn't reproduce the problem again. It's the first time that I see this strange behavior. I think the source of the problem is at the `CodeName` of `sheet2`.

Does anyone knows some workaround for this problem, or some reason for this to happen?

Comment: General question - why are you using the VSTO wrapper at all?

Comment: Because I need to manage controls placed on my worksheets...

Comment: I think this is not possible. "Managed controls can only be added to host items, which act as containers" ([Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc442817.aspx))

Comment: ah i understand ! you are creating winforms comboboxes (not "excel" dropdowns, but "windows" comboboxes)

Comment: Are you developing an application-level add-in or a document-level add-in?

Comment: Try to use `Globals.Factory.HasVstoObject` on `sheet` before calling `Globals.Factory.GetVstoObject` and see whether it returns `true` or `false`.

Comment: It returns False for this worksheet. It means that the "Sheet1" have a vsto object but the "Sheet2" doesn't have. And when I try to get "Sheet2" vsto object, I get the "Sheet1" vsto object. What can I do to get the "Sheet2" vsto object in this case?

Comment: Can you check whether `sheet == Globals.Factory.GetVstoObject(sheet).InnerObject`, whether `sheet.Index == Globals.Factory.GetVstoObject(sheet).Index` and whether `sheet.CodeName == Globals.Factory.GetVstoObject(sheet).CodeName`? Also please let me know all these values.

Comment: `sheet Is Globals.Factory.GetVstoObject(sheet).InnerObject` is true for my "Sheet1" but it's False for "Sheet2". In your other two expressions, only the right side (the vsto objects) have definition for `CodeName` and `Index`, so the comparsion was not possible. But anyway, the `Index` of my 2 sheets (vsto objects of them) is returning 1 and the `CodeName` is "Sheet1" in both of my sheets. I don't know why the `GetVstoObject` is returning the same answer (the vsto object of the first sheet) for both sheets...

Comment: @LeonardoValverde `sheet` must be either of type [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel._worksheet_members.aspx) or [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.worksheet_members.aspx) both define `Index` and `CodeName` properties. What is the type of `sheet`?

Comment: Wow, you was right, I'm sorry. I couldn't call this functions from Immediate Window, but when I call Index or CodeName from my code, it works. The type is `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet`. `sheet.Index Is Globals.Factory.GetVstoObject(sheet).Index` is the same of `2 Is 1`, but `sheet.CodeName Is Globals.Factory.GetVstoObject(sheet).CodeName` is the same of `"Sheet1" Is "Sheet1"`. NICE DISCOVERY! `sheet.Name` is returning "Sheet2", but `sheet.CodeName` is returning "Sheet1". Do you think this is the source of my problem?

Comment: I didn't make any renaming on these sheets before. In short: I have two sheets, named as "Sheet1" and "Sheet2", but both have the `CodeName` equals to "Sheet1".

Comment: Code names are unique within a workbook. So if both sheets are in the same workbook and you did not delete any sheets, then if the code names are same it means they are the same sheet. That said, I still need more information. Can you update you question with more details on all sheets created and deleted, in what order, whether any sheets are moved and the number of times and order `GetVstoObject` is being called. Also before and after every call to `GetVstoObject` add print statements for both native and managed sheet objects to see the values of Index, CodeName, InnerObject and Name.